# Regex with dynamic requirement

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have string:

`var a = '/c/Slug-A/Slug-B/Slug-C'`

I have 3 possibility:

`var b = 'Slug-A' || 'Slug-B' || 'Slug-C'`

My expectation:

```
if (b === 'Slug-A') return 'Slug B - Slug C';
if (b === 'Slug-B') return 'Slug A - Slug C';
if (b === 'Slug-C') return 'Slug A - Slug B';
```

What I've done so far:

```
a.replace(b,'')
.replace(/\/c\//,'') // clear /c/
.replace(/-/g,' ')
.replace(/\//g,' - ')
```

Then, I'm stuck

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what happened to variable a its not being used i think the question is not clear

Comment: @prime let me know if my answer helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way

```
var a = '/c/Slug-A/Slug-B/Slug-C'
var b = 'Slug-A'
 //var b = 'Slug-B'
 //var b = 'Slug-C'

var k = a.replace(b,'')
.replace(/\/c\//,'') // clear /c/
.replace(/-/g,' ')
.match(/[a-zA-Z -]+/g).join(" - ")

console.log(k)
```

working array [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/mogv9mxz/)

Comment: Thanks but it return `SlugB - SlugC` instead of `Slug B - Slug C`

Comment: Please change you answer into working answer. I accept your answer. Previous accepted answer fail when I change `Slug-A/Slug-B/Slug-C` into different string like `Some-Word/Another-Word/Another-Words`. Anyway, what `.match(/[a-zA-Z -]+/g)` do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var a = '/c/Slug-A/Slug-B/Slug-C'
var b = 'Slug-A' || 'Slug-B' || 'Slug-C'
var reg = new RegExp(b.replace(/([A-z]$)/,function(val){return '[^'+val+']'}),'g');
a.match(reg).map(function(val){return val.replace('-',' ')}).join(' - ');
```

**Explication:**

the replacement of the string `b` catch the last latter of the string and replace it with the `^` regex sign. this mean that instead of capture it it will ignore it.

That mean that mean that now it will match only the `Slag-` that isn't contain the last char.

All there is to do is to return it with any join you like.

Comment: Perfect!! Would be great if you elaborate a little. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I made it as simple as possible.

```js
var a = '/c/Slug-A/Slug-B/Slug-C';
var b = 'Slug-A';

var regex = new RegExp(b+'|\/c\/|-|\/','g');

alert(a.replace(regex, " ").trim().replace(/(\s.*?)\s+/,'$1 - '));

//OR

alert(a.replace(regex, " ").trim().match(/\w+\s\w/g).join(' - '));
```

**Explanation**

1) `b+'|\/c\/|-|\/','g'` = matches `b` value, `/c/` , `-` and `/`

2) `a.replace(regex, " ")` = replace all the matched part by space. so a would be`Slug A Slug B`

3) `.replace(/(\s.*?)\s+/,'$1 - ')` = match two spaces with anything within the spaces. And then replace it with the `match + ' - '` appended to it.

**Note**  that we have grouped the part `(\s.*?)` in the regex `(\s.*?)\s+`. So this grouping is done so that It can be used while replacing it with a new text. `$1` holds the grouped part of the matched text so `$1 = " A"`. So what I am doing is I match the regex Eg : `" A "` and replace only the grouped part ie `" A"` with `" A"` + `" - "` = `" A - "`.

4) `.match(/\w+\s\w/g).join(' - ')` = match all the part where characters followed by a space followed by a character. `match` will return a array of matched parts. So then I join this array by using `join`.

Comment: Working for the first. The second fail when I have different string like `Some-Word/Another-Word/Another-Words`. Upvoted for your answer. Thanks